# How to fill missing part of character's head?

Tags: modeling

I have a  model where part of head is missing. Can I fill it fast?
[image]
I've tried to use grid fill, but it's just filling it like this:
[image]
How can I fix it and keep resolution of original poligons?

Comment: Follow the existing loops (extrude edges from the top in the shape of the head until they hit the bottom unconnected edges).

Answer (score 2):

*Grid Fill* is worth a try, if you have matched vertex-counts (as it seems), with the right number of spans, and offset. For more control,  you might have more luck with *Bridge Edge Loops* > *Blend Surface*, for an incomplete fill, missing out the corners:

[image]

... counting the cuts to match, and filling the remaining faces as a second operation.

Comment: Sorry, but Bridge Edge Loops doesn't work for me at all. In your case you have right side of an eye and you can connect your edges with it. But I don't have it, so I just getting a total mess.